# How can i convert a phone number to american format phone number in php?

Tags: php

I have a phone number shuffled with hyphens.I want convert this phone number to american format by removing unwanted hyphens and adding necessary hyphens using php.
For example

```
$phone=123--45-6-4523;
```

I want to cahnge the above to

```
$phone=123-456-4523;
```

Comment: I suggest that you make an attempt to solve your coding problems yourself. If they don't work post your best try here and explain what issues you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$phone="123--45-6-4523";
$phone = str_replace("-", "", $phone);// remove all the dashes
$phone = substr($phone, 0,3) . "-" .  // add the two dashes in the right places
         substr($phone, 3,3) . "-" . substr($phone, 6);

echo $phone;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
123-456-4523
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$phone=123--45-6-4523;
$phone=str_split(str_ireplace('-','',$phone));
$c=0;
$no='';
foreach($phone as $a)
{
if($c==2||$c==5)
$no.='-';
$no.=$a
c++;
}
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$phone="123--45-6-4523";

$phone=str_replace("-","",$phone);
$american_phone="";
for ($i=0;$i<strlen($phone);$i++)
{
$american_phone.=$phone[$i];
if ($i==2 || $i==5)
$american_phone.="-";
}
echo $american_phone;
```

I am removing the hyphens and then add 2 hyphens after 3rd and 6th digit. I am not aware of american numbers. If you need something else, specify...

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/^(\d{3})[-]*(\d{3})[-]*(\d{4})$/i', '$1-$2-$3', '123--456-4523');
```

This solves your above case but if there are more try modifying the regular expression.